# Send two request to php in android

Tags: java, android

I have this code and when I click on a button this function runs but this function sends two request to php and php saves two records in database...?

```
public void send()
{
    //get message from message box
    final String  msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = null;
    //check whether the msg empty or not
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    if(msg.length() > 0) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", "MSG"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message", msg));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            LinearLayout Lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MSGes);
            TextView MyView = new TextView(this);
            MyView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            MyView.setText(msg);
            MyView.setId(Integer.valueOf(result.toString()));
            Lay.addView(MyView);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            } 

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and logcat:

09-15 17:50:32.328: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
09-15 17:50:32.328: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
09-15 17:50:32.758: E/log_tag(3651): Error converting result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
09-15 17:50:35.188: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
09-15 17:50:35.188: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
09-15 17:50:38.168: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
09-15 17:50:38.168: W/SingleClientConnManager(3651): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
09-15 17:50:38.538: E/log_tag(3651): Error converting result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've made the typo here:

```
httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Exclude the first line, and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

The error you should be concerned about is

> E/log_tag(3651): Error converting result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

You need to determine why there is only one element in the list when you are expecting more. I suggest that you print out the stacktrace in order to track down the problem.

Better yet, catch a specific exception rather than every exception. `catch (Exception e)` is considered a bad practice because you can potentially squelch serious errors in your code.